# Can I compile the SP below

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to read a column based on the variable provided then pass the column information to update the row.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE updatePersonUUID01(
       PFirstName IN PERSON.First_Name%TYPE,
       PLastName  IN PERSON.Last_Name%TYPE,
       PPersonID  out number)
IS
BEGIN
select person_id into ppersonid 
  from Person
  where 
       Person.First_Name = PFirstName 
  AND  Person.Last_Name  = PLastName;

  UPDATE person
  SET Login_uuid = NULL 
  WHERE 
      person_id = ppersonid; 

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Can you compile it..? We can't answer that. Did you try, and what happened? If you got an error then you need to tell us what it is, and include the related table DDL, in your question.

Comment: It seems to be a long way around to do `UPDATE person SET Login_uuid = NULL where First_Name = :FN and Last_Name = :LN` with no need for PL/SQL at all. And  using a `commit` in a stored procedure is discouraged--it's like the venerable `goto` from back in the day: normally discouraged, but appropriate when you have a good reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provided you have a table in your current schema called `person` within your schema with 
`person_id` column of `number` type, and `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Login_uuid` columns.

But, don't forget to handle at least `no_data_found` ( might be better `too_many_rows` too ) exception for your `select` statement as :

```
begin
   select person_id 
     into ppersonid 
     from Person p
    where p.First_Name = PFirstName 
      and p.Last_Name  = PLastName;
 exception when no_data_found then ppersonid :=null;
           when too_many_rows then ppersonid :=null;
end;
```